# Adjust background container to page height not screen height.

Tags: css, background, containers

My problem is that my background container is displayed only till the screen bottom. I can't see it in the part after that. I tried nearly everything but nothing seems to work for me. I want it to be adjusted according to page size.

```
<body>
<div id="profilebg">

<!-- Other divs -->

</div>
</body>
```

And my CSS is

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#profilebg
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    width:80%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: If #profilebg is your background container, why are you using absolute positioning?

Comment: I tried without using absolute positioning but that was also not working. Tried a lot of things, read a lot of articles and there somewhere I read this so thought to give it a try.

Comment: Remove the `position: absolute;`, the `height: 100%;`, the `top: 0;`, and the `bottom: 0;`

Comment: I agree, i personally try to avoid absolute positioning where possible. Please see my edit answer with a second fiddle using relative positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a height, it defaults to 'auto' which is determined by the height of the content.

If you float something inside of the content be sure to add an element with ccs style `clear:both` so that the parent can correctly determine it's height.

Similarly if any child of an element uses absolute positioning, it will not be able to determine it's height automatically as the absolutely positioned child is no longer in the same scope as the parent.

A sample working style would be:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

#profilebg
{
    margin: 0 10%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

**Edit:** More concise CSS styles - width is redundant with margins

**Edit 2:** Add line about absolute positioning

**Edit 3:** Div structure to achieve request in below comments:

```
<div id="page-container">
    <div id="header-container">
        <!-- Put your header here -->
    </div>
    <div id="body-container">
        <div id="profilebg">
            <!-- Profile BG Container -->
        </div>
        <!-- Any other body content here -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer-container">
        <!-- Footer content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working if I remove all absolute positioned divs from my container. Any idea what is the reason?

Comment: The parent can't determine it's height when it has children with absolute positioning since the absolute positioning takes it out of the scope of the parent

Comment: @linpar if you give us an idea of what you are trying to do with the absolute positioning of some elements, a solution that will work for you may be possible

Comment: Actually I am not very good at CSS so for positioning of my divs I was using absolute as it is pretty straight forward. 
Now, one more thing if you can help me with it. I want my footer to stick on the bottom of page so should I use top:100%, bottom:0% with absolute positioning or is there any other better method?

Comment: @linpar Do you mean you want the footer to always be at on the page but at the bottom or always at the bottom of your content (scroll down to see footer)?

Comment: I want my footer always at the bottom of content. But if the content is not filling up a page(not scrollable) then I want it to be at the bottom of page leaving some sapce between the content and footer.

Comment: @linpar Please see Edit 3 for details on how to accomplish your request

Comment: @linpar That is what this site is all about

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to work for what you want to achieve. I've removed the `bottom:0;` and changed `height` to `min-height`.

```
html, body {   
    height:100%; 
}

#profilebg {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    width:80%;   
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    top: 0;
    display: block;   
}
```

**EDIT** Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXaYS/)

**EDIT 2** Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXaYS/2/) with relative positioning.

Comment: I guess it is not working with my other divs. I tried <p> tags and it was working with them.

Comment: If you're using absolute positioning for everything contained within the `#profilebg` then it will not be able to work out the initial height.

Comment: I am using absolute positioning for some containers present in #profilebg
I tried relative positioning but that also is not working.